Clearing an audio.src that pointed to a blob url after revoking that blob url?
When fetching a blob for an audio file, as in the code sample below (no cached on disk but held in memory only), when the blob is no longer needed and the object URL is revoked, what is the proper way to clear the source from the audio element such that blob will be released in the garbage collection cycle?
I don't want to get rid of the audio element itself and I don't want to wait until a new valid audio source is selected. If the source is set to "" then later audio.src is the http address rather than "" or the blob url. (Unless I have a coding error elsewhere at the moment causing this.)
Is there a "clean" way to do this such that a console.log error is not generated and, perhaps, only the 'emptied'' event is triggered/fired?
Is setting src = ""; audio.load(); the correct approach?
Thank you.
fetch(
  `http://${url}/audio/${trackId}`,
  { method: 'GET', mode: 'same-origin', cache: 'no-store' }
)
.then( http => {
   if ( !http.ok ) {
       throw new TypeError('Network response was not ok.');
    } else {
      const contentType = http.headers.get('content-type');
      if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('audio/mpeg')) {
        throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got an audio file!");
      }
    }
  return http.blob();
})
.then( result => {
  let
     objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( result )
  ;
  audio_elem.src = objectURL;
})
;

Added after initial post.
I think this is the primary item causing my code to fail and, perhaps, my expectation is in error. You can see that after the audio source is set to "" when it is logged it returns the http address. I was expecting "". If the element is viewed in developer tools in the DOM, it shows a source of "". I'll just have to test the source string to see if it starts with "blob:http" or just "blob".
Well, after I caught on to what @Phil commented (thank you), removing the attribute is what is recommended and it works; and I can just test for
if (audio.src === "") as expected.
I tested this in Firefox and am using Manjaro Linux.


var
   blob = new Blob(),
   objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob ),
   audio = document.createElement('audio')
;
audio.src = objectURL;
console.log(audio.src);
// blob:null/405ed312-09d2-48e4-a270-71ce8006713b
audio.src = "";
console.log(audio.src);
// https://stacksnippets.net/js


audio.src = objectURL;
console.log(audio.src);
// blob:null/405ed312-09d2-48e4-a270-71ce8006713b
audio.removeAttribute('src');
console.log(audio.src);
// ... nothing appears
console.log(`${audio.src === null} ${audio.src === ""} ${'src' in audio}`);
// false true true
audio.src = objectURL;
console.log(audio.src);
// blob:null/405ed312-09d2-48e4-a270-71ce8006713b




Have you tried removeAttribute()
